# How can i fetch (select then delete) from a database table?

Tags: mysql, select, fetch

I have a stream table (memory table), and a script which is inserting in this table (from 1 row/min to 100 rows/sec). I need to fetch 1000 rows every 5 seconds, i mean select top 1000 rows and then delete that selected rows.

My select query is so simple:

```
SELECT * FROM vdp_stream WHERE user=xxx
```

My problem is actually i cannot query a DELETE sql, because maybe some new rows be appended between the time that i `SELECT` and `DELETE`. Am i right? Is there any solution to fetch rows from a table?

UPDATE my table structure:

```
vdp_stream
---------------------
user CHAR(30)
x    INT
y    INT
```

Comment: What is the table structure? It sounds like you should be using a messaging system, not an RDBMS for this task.

Comment: yes i know it sounds bad with RDBMS but i need to know any solution for situations like this in RDBMS databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to continue doing this using a table I would suggest using UPDATE, SELECT and DELETE statements within a transaction.  Something like this perhaps -

```
START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE vdp_stream
SET selected = 1
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 1000;

SELECT *
FROM vdp_stream
WHERE selected = 1;

DELETE
FROM vdp_stream
WHERE selected = 1;

COMMIT;
```

**UPDATE** - as the default isolation level for InnoDB is REPEATABLE READ you can omit the update and just do the SELECT and DELETE based on the same criteria -

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT *
FROM vdp_stream
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 1000;

DELETE
FROM vdp_stream
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 1000;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: do i really need that `selected` ? If table is locked during the transaction why would i need that column?